# Rounding number in VB

Tags: vb.net, rounding

How to round a number into 2 decimals, for example

```
12.72 --> 12.70
12.76 --> 12.75
```

For instance

```
decimal from 1.01 to 1.02 will round off to 1.00
decimal from 1.03 to 1.04 will round off to 1.05
decimal from 1.06 to 1.07 will round off to 1.05
decimal from 1.08 to 1.09 will round off to 1.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to round to the closest 1/20th. So multiply the number by 20, round it, and divide by 20:

```
n = Math.Round(n * 20) / 20
```

Comment: Thank you, but could u please explain why it should be multiply/divided by 20?

Comment: @Sollo: You are rounding to the closest 0.05 step, and that is 1/20.